# Layout for chat app in Android

Tags: android, xml, layout, chat

I'm making a chat for Android and I need to make a main xml layout. 
There is going to be a TextView to display history, EditText and Send Button. All view should be positioned like in whatsapp. EditText and Button at the bottom of a screen. The rest of the space goes to the TextView.
So how is it possible to do it, so it would look nice at any screen and any orientation?
I tried to do it with android:layout_weight, but I don't think it's going to be very portable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are trying to mimic the layout of another app you can examine how it was built using "Dump View Hierarchy for UI Automater". Also why don't you think layout_weight is going to be portable? Do you specific reasons you think that?

Comment: because layout_weight sets the proportions, but the height of my editText/Button is fixed. So for different screen sizes, diffrerent height would be given to them, leaving some space.

Comment: Are you related to [the one asking this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890488/what-android-layout-should-i-use-for-a-simple-process-mapping-app) by any chance? You both seem to be big fans of creating Whatsapp-similar layouts

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a single TextView is the best way to achieve this.

I'd recommend using a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) instead of a giant TextView to hold the entire conversation history.  Each element in the ListView would hold a single TextView and any other required views to display each message in the history, and it will by default allow for scrolling up and down to view the entire history.  You can then just adjust the text size to handle different screen sizes.

This is how the default Android Messaging app is implemented, but you can customize each item in the ListView to make it look how you want (like WhatsApp, for example).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, of Course I'm gonna use more than just TextView. I just said it for example. But thanks for the answer anyway. Thought my main problem is to position the views correctly

Answer (score 1):

> because layout_weight sets the proportions, but the height of my editText/Button is fixed

So? Don't put `android:layout_weight` on the fixed portion.

> So for different screen sizes, diffrerent height would be given to them, leaving some space.

Then don't put `android:layout_weight` on the fixed portion. You are hitting yourself on the head with a hammer, then complaining that your head hurts.

Step #1: Vertical `LinearLayout`.

Step #2: Transcript `TextView` inside the `LinearLayout`, with a height of 0 and a weight of 1.

Step #3: `EditText` and `Button` (in a horizontal `LinearLayout`?), inside the vertical `LinearLayout`, with a height of `wrap_content` and no weight specified (defaults to 0).

Your fixed-height stuff, with a height of `wrap_content`, will get its allocation of pixels, and your transcript `TextView` will get all remaining pixels, courtesy of its weight of 1.

I also echo physphil's suggestion to use a `ListView` in transcript mode for your chat transcript, rather than the `TextView`.